# Code in run method not running

Tags: java, javafx, runnable

I have a program that encrypts text
The code below activates when the user presses a button, AES Base64 run when type.getText() returns AES Base64, however, Strong Text Encryptor (from Jasypt) doesn't when type.getText() returns Strong Text Encryptor, the reason I'm using runnables is because I want my progressbar to update and not freeze the GUI.

Note that I'm using JavaFX FXML and this is the controller class, which implements Initializable.

```
switch (type.getText()) {

                case "AES Base64":
                    t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                strToEncrypt = input.getText();
                                bar.setProgress(0.11);
                                strPssword = pass.getText();
                                bar.setProgress(0.22);
                                AES.setKey(strPssword);
                                bar.setProgress(0.33);
                                AES.encrypt(strToEncrypt.trim());
                                bar.setProgress(0.44);
                                output.setText(AES.getEncryptedString());
                                bar.setProgress(0.55);
                                log.setText("");
                                bar.setProgress(0.66);
                                log.appendText("String to encrypt " + strToEncrypt + "\n");
                                bar.setProgress(0.77);
                                log.appendText("Password " + strPssword + "\n");
                                bar.setProgress(0.88);
                                log.appendText("Encrypted String " + AES.getEncryptedString() + "\n");
                                bar.setProgress(1.0);
                                hasChecked = false;
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                bar.setProgress(0);
                                Error(ex.getMessage());
                                Logger(ex.getMessage());
                            }
                        }

                    });
                    t.start();
                    break;

                case "Strong Text Encryptor":
                    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                StrongTextEncryptor textEncryptor = new StrongTextEncryptor();
                                bar.setProgress(0.33);
                                textEncryptor.setPassword(pass.getText());
                                bar.setProgress(0.66);
                                output.setText(textEncryptor.encrypt(input.getText()));
                                bar.setProgress(1.0);
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                bar.setProgress(0);
                                Error(ex.getMessage());
                                Logger(ex.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                 }
```

Comment: Well, you never start the thread, so it's not really surprising, is it?

Comment: @JBNizet Didn't I call t.start()? Sorry I'm really new to Java

Comment: @JBNizet OH Oh my god I didn't realize! Thank you!

Comment: Just look at your code. No, you didn't. You did it for the AES thread. But not for the Jasypt one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`run()` method will be invoked only when you start the `Thread`** which you did in your first case i.e., for `case "AES Base64"`, but you did not start the `Thread` in the second case, so simply add `t.start()` to your `case "Strong Text Encryptor"`